# MongoDB referenceError: Schema is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've read the questions in this topic. But I wasn't able to find the solution, because I think I defined the Schema well.

My models.js is like this.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
password: String,
created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
done: Boolean,
priority: String,
deadLine: String,
masterDetailNote: String
});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);
```

My api.js is like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);

router.use(function(req, res, next) {

if (req.method === "GET") {
    return next();
}

if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.redirect('#/login');
}
return next();
});
router.route('/posts')

//returns all todos
.get(function(req, res) {

Todo.find(function(err, data) {

    if (err) {
        return res.send(500, err);
    }

    return res.send(data);

 });

})

//creates a new todo
.post(function(req, res) {

var todo = new Todo();
todo.title = req.body.title;
todo.done = req.body.done;
todo.priority = req.body.priority;
todo.deadLine = req.body.deadLine;
todo.masterDetailNote = req.body.masterDetailNote;

todo.save(function(err, post) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send(500, err);
    }
    return res.json(todo);
  });
}); 

router.route('/posts/:id')

//egy bizonyos Todo-t hoz vissza
.get(function(req, res) {
Todo.findById(req.params.id, function(err, post) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json(post);
});
})

//frissít egy todot
.put(function(req, res) {
Todo.findById(req.params.id, function(err, post) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);

    todo.title = req.body.title;
    todo.done = req.body.done;
    todo.priority = req.body.priority;
    todo.deadLine = req.body.deadLine;
    todo.masterDetailNote = req.body.masterDetailNote;

    todo.save(function(err, post) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(post);
    });
   });
 })

.delete(function(req, res) {
Todo.remove({
    _id: req.params.id
}, function(err) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json("deleted :(");
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

When i try to strat the server it shows the error message.

```
var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);
```

RefferenceError: todoSchema is not defined. I don't really understand because it is defined exactly like the userSchema. But I can use the userSyhema without any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of `todoSchema` is not defined in `app.js` use without like: `mongoose.model('modelName')`

so in your api.js use like

```
var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo');// ensure first model file is loaded
```

instead of

```
var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);
```

**OR**

```
require('modelDirectory/model.js');//load model file first then use model from there 
var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo');
```

**OR**

create separate file for each model. for example in `todo.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
done: Boolean,
priority: String,
deadLine: String,
masterDetailNote: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);
```

and in `api.js`

```
var Todo = require('modelDirectory/todo.js');
```

Comment: In that case, the error message is "MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Todo". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)".

Comment: load model file first. see answer or portion @R.Andris

Comment: That should fix it but it doesn't find it. Error: Cannot find module ./models/models.js. I don't understand, that really exists in that folder.

Comment: how your directory hierarchy ?                                                                                     -api.js                                                                                                         -models/model.js                                                                                           then should be like `require('./models/models');`

Comment: api.js is in the routes folder. models.js is in the models folder. Bot folders are in the some main folder

Comment: so use like `require('../models/models.js');`

Comment: Oh, that made the trick. I learn to code on my own and it is really difficult sometimes. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

You missing few lines of code.

First in `models.js` add

`var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);`

`var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);`

`module.exports = {User: User, Todo: Todo}`

Then in `api.js`

`var models = require('./models.js')`

`var Todo = models.Todo;`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to require that file in app.js and

```
require('YOUR PATH')
```

export the file from model page

```
var User=mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
  module.exports = User
```

Answer (score 0):

`Todo.js` file:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var todoSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    date: String,
    completed: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("todo",todoSchema);
```

This is my models file Todo.js. İf you wanna don't get this error, you should import your model file in your api file.
For example I have a api file `todos.js` under routes file.
I do get, post, put operation in `routes/todos.js`.
I imported models file in the `todos.js`.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Todo = require("../models/Todo");

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  
    Todo.find().then((todos) => {
      res.json(todos);
    }).catch((err) => {
      res.json(err);
    });
  
});
```